# What is the alternative for classes like org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.WriteTag & org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.PresentTag in Struts 2?

Tags: struts2, struts-1

I'm trying to migrate a part of my existing project from Struts 1.1 to Struts 2.5 framework. But I'm facing while replacing the tags like "write" tag in the "struts-bean.tld" and "present" tag in the "struts-logic.tld" tag libraries with their corresponding Struts 2 tags as these tags are not present in the in-built "struts-tags.tld" file of Struts2. Can anyone please help me out ?

Comment: I'd probably just read an S2 tutorial or look at the tag reference docs. There are no direct equivalents, nor should you ever need them, since you now have a complete expression language with OGNL, and direct access to action properties via JSP EL.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton for the suggestions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We no more require the struts 1 tags.
Remove these tags for your jsp pages and also remove the .tld files (struts-html, struts-logic,struts-bean) from the folder you have placed in workspace.

```html
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-html.tld" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-logic.tld" prefix="logic"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean"%>
```

Struts 2 uses only a single tld, the struts-tags.tld. Add this in your jsp

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
```

Comment: Hi Balaji, Thanks for answering. Could you please also tell me which tags should I use instead of tags using "org.apache.struts.taglib.bean.WriteTag" & "org.apache.struts.taglib.logic.PresentTag" classes used in Struts 1 to serve the same purpose in Struts 2? Basically I'm not able to find the appropriate replacements for above tags so that I can change my JSP files keeping the existing functionality intact.

Comment: Making these snippets is pointless since there's nothing to execute, and you seem to have not actually answered the question. The question was what to replace the S1 tags with, not what the new S2 TLD is.